# Dynamics 365 DiscoveryServiceProxy sometimes returns no results

Tags: .net, vb.net, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

first post so please be kind.

I'm attempting to return a list of organizations that a user has access to in Dynamics 365 (Online).

This function works about 50% of the time, it authenticates fine, and returns the org list, but randomly it won't return any orgs at all.

I'm using a logon in the format XXX@XXX.onmicrosoft.com, accessing dynamics 365 itself is fine.

I already have the organization endpoints and can create the organization service just fine, just struggling getting consistent results from the function.

I've looked into any sort of max call attempts on the service, used fiddler to trace the requests and responses for any clues, but nothing so far, and no errors.

Any help would be appretiated

```
Public Shared Function retrieveOrganizations(conn As Connectiondata) As List(Of orgDetails)

    ' New Org List
    Dim orgList As New List(Of orgDetails)

    ' Accepts all certs
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(Function() True)

    ' Create a management service
    Dim serviceManagement As IServiceManagement(Of IDiscoveryService) = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement(Of IDiscoveryService)(New Uri("https://disco.crm11.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc"))

    ' Find what type of endpoint we need to use
    Dim endpointType As AuthenticationProviderType = serviceManagement.AuthenticationType

    ' Set the credentials based on the auth type and conn details
    Dim authCredentials As AuthenticationCredentials = GetCredentials(serviceManagement, endpointType, conn)

    'Create discovery service proxy
    Dim discoService As New DiscoveryServiceProxy(serviceManagement, authCredentials.ClientCredentials)

    ' Authenticate the service
    discoService.Authenticate()

    'Retrieve Organization details
    Dim orgRequest As New RetrieveOrganizationsRequest()

    ' Cast the response
    Dim allOrgs As RetrieveOrganizationsResponse = DirectCast(discoService.Execute(orgRequest), RetrieveOrganizationsResponse)

    'Print all organization(s)(instances) endpoint.
    For Each orgdetail As OrganizationDetail In allOrgs.Details

        ' Create a new object
        orgList.Add(New orgDetails With {.friendlyName = orgdetail.FriendlyName, .ID = orgdetail.OrganizationId.ToString})

    Next

    ' Return the list
    Return orgList

End Function
```